# .persist() line sometimes leads to Java Out of Heap Space error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, elastic-map-reduce

As far as I know, when you use `.persist()`, writing the line `persist` sets only the persistence level, and then the next `action` in the script will cause the actual persistence work to be invoked.

However, sometimes, seemingly depending on the dataframe, `persist()` will lead to a Java out of heap space error.

What is the intended behavior of persist, and why could this simple line actually lead to this memory error?

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of [RDD Persistence](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) is to store intermediate results in memory, allowing faster access on subsequent use. There are several different levels of persistence, ranging from `MEMORY_ONLY` (the default), over `MEMORY_AND_DISK`, up to `DISK_ONLY`. Persisting purely to memory means that there has to be enough heap space for the persist to work. If you run out of heap memory you can

- go for a lower persistence level,
- reduce the size of your partitions,
- reduce the total number of persisted RDD stages, e.g., by `unpersist`ing them.

Finding the right balance is one of the key challenges in Spark to achieve a good tradeoff between memory and CPU usage.

Comment: while I agree that is likely what is happening, I'm also asking why writing the line `persist` actually invokes any tasks at all. I was under the impression that it was lazily evaluated. and it seems to immediate invoke work in some cases.

Comment: @Kristian: That sounds indeed unusual. Do you have a minimal example that would show the problem? Calling `persist()` mainly registers the RDD in the Spark context for persistence, which should not require a significant amount of memory.